# Invited_by_id for Devise invitable gem is always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am using Devises Invitable gem, and it works fine except that invited_by_id is always nil.

I am inviting by the following code:

```
   user = User.invite!(
                    :email => user.email,
                    :first_name => user.first_name,
                    :last_name => user.last_name,
                    :user_type => user.user_type,
                    :account_id => user.account_id,
                    :invited_by_id => current_user.id
                )
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: Where are you writing above code?

Comment: I am using this code in a module which I invokes from a controller. I have also tried to extract the code out directly in the controller, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Try to inspect current_user before this call in controller.

Comment: what if you write `User.invite!(user)`

Comment: `:invited_by_id => current_user.id` replace it by `:invited_by_id => user.id`

Comment: @Shweta current_user is not nil an is accessable.

Comment: @RajarshiDas if you would use user.id, it would just set the invited_by_id to  itself.

Comment: @Dofs according to https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#send-an-invitation .. If user is already created use ```user.invite!(current_user)``` In your case it seems to be created

Comment: I mean to say `current_user.invite!(....:invited_by_id => user.id)`

Comment: @Shweta It worked if I used user = User.invite!(
                {
                    :email => user.email,
                    :first_name => user.first_name,
                    :last_name => user.last_name,
                    :user_type => user.user_type,
                    :account_id => user.account_id,
                    :invited_by_id => current_user.id
                }, current_user
            )

Comment: @Dofs Thanks, that last comment put me on the right track. Interestingly, you don't need the `:invited_by_id => current_user.id` element as the user is passed in from the object at the end only as noted in this article: https://gorails.com/blog/how-to-create-invitations-from-any-model-with-devise-invitable

Comment: Maybe the user id type is different than the type of the invited_by_id column